# Why would this cached geo query be slower in elasticsearch than the uncached?

Tags: performance, caching, elasticsearch, geo

Looking at the query below, I've added a cached geo_bounding_box filter in front of my geo_shape filter. My expectation after reading https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geo-caching.html was that this query should be faster. However, in my benchmarking the query with both filters turns out to be slightly slower on average, and MUCH slower in the worst case. Am I doing something wrong, or misinterpreting the doc?

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                        {"geo_bounding_box" : {
                            "_cache": True,
                            "properties.center" : {
                                "top_left" : {
                                    "lat" : math.ceil(float(lat)),
                                    "lon" : math.floor(float(lon))
                                },
                                "bottom_right" : {
                                    "lat" : math.floor(float(lat)),
                                    "lon" : math.ceil(float(lon))
                                }
                            }
                        }},
                        {"geo_shape": {
                            "geometry": {
                                "relation": "intersects",
                                "shape": {
                                    "coordinates": [lon,lat],
                                    "type": "point"
                                }
                            }
                        }}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lowercase JSON boolean values:

```
"_cache": true
```